# How to add comma in the list value in ATG

Tags: java, list, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

In ATG i have a one list and one properties file i need to add comma(,) value in the list

Sample.java

```
List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList();
```

sample.properties

```
sampleList=/
            a,b,c ,\
            c,d,e
```

in ATG default comma is mean by a next value but i need comma(,) in the string value. In iteration time comma is separated the values

Expected Result:

```
0=a,b,c
1=c,d,e
```

actual Result :

```
0=a
1=b
2=c
3=d
4=e
5=f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double comma (,,) is escaping special meaning of comma in ATG configuration files.

```
sampleList=/
        a,,b,,c ,\
        c,,d,,e
```